# Problems with iPhone SDK StoreKit

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

In my iPhone app Im using StoreKit to make it possible for users to buy subscriptions in the app. The problem I'm having is that suddenly everytime I start the app SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased is sent to the observer so the app tries to buy the subscription again and again. And if I try to buy the subscription again from the list of subscriptions in the app I get a message saying "You've already purchased this In App Purchase but it hasn't been downloaded." then failedTransaction is called with SKErrorPaymentCancelled.

EDIT: I have now found a lot of threads about this in the Apple Developer Forum, for example: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/73818 and /thread/73572, it seems like a lot of developers have the same problem..

This is the code I'm using, can you see something wrong with it?

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
            break;
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

-(void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error"); 
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Cancel");
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

-(void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self subscribe:transaction];
}

-(void) completeTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self subscribe:transaction];
}

-(void)subscribe: (SKPaymentTransaction*)transaction { 
    NSInteger errorCode = //Connects to my server that verifies receipt with Apple server etc..
    if (errorCode==0) {
        [self provideContent];
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to Apple support I was able to solve this issue. It seems to be a problem from Apple that has now been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem when using the StoreKit the first time and it happened because as I was implemented the code I was leaving transactions unfinished.

So, when you start the app, you'll need to loop through the queue and finish all transactions. You shouldn't need to do this is you cover all outcomes (which, based on the code above, you did).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After I asked this question I have found several threads in the Apple Developer Forums, with a lot of people all having the same problem. Something must have changed as we have been using StoreKit for almost a year without problems...